# 'Insufficient Privileges' error while deleting an Opportunity team member I just created

Tags: opportunity

I got a problem when a non-Administrator user tries to remove an Opportunity team member.

I checked the Salesforce documentation, 3 condictions are necessary in order to do that:
 1. ”Read” on users
 2. "Edit” on opportunities
 3. Owner of the opportunity, or above the owner in your organization’s role hierarchy

My use case is a standard user (not Administrator) who owns the Opportunity (condition 3 verified). His profile allows the update of Opportunities (Opportunity EDIT permission is checked: condition 2 checked).

Regarding condition 1, I didn't find any EDIT Permission on the object User, but my Organization Wide defaults settings for Users are 'Puclic Read Only'.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi arnaud, Does this users profile have Delete permission on the Standard Object 'Opportunities'? This sounds like an issue with the Role Hierarchy. Granting 'Modify All' access on the 'Opportunities' object to the users Profile will allow deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the permission to delete Opportunity?

Opportunity being the parent for Opp. Team Member and the permission for that object would be "controlled by parent". Only if you have the permission to delete the opportunity you can delete the team member.